# 500 internal server error when calling Sharepoint 2010 search.asmx

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to call Sharepoint 2010 search web service from a client application in .NET 4.5
I added the service reference with no problems, I modified web.config to allow proper authentication (NTLM) but when I call the Query method, I get a 500 server error with the message:

Server was unable to process request. ---> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 --->; Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904

I've tried several things, and what I've found really puzzles me:

When using Fiddler to analyse the requests, here is the request that fails (just the body part):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
               <queryXml>&lt;QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;SupportedFormats&gt;&lt;Format&gt;urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document&lt;/Format&gt;&lt;/SupportedFormats&gt;&lt;Context&gt;&lt;QueryText language='en-US' type='STRING'&gt;ACCORDION&lt;/QueryText&gt;&lt;/Context&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/QueryPacket&gt;
                </queryXml>
          </Query>
     </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When looking at the web service description (by pointing the browser to _vti_bin/search.asmx?op=Query), I realized that the namespaces now appearing in `<s:Body` should be in `<s:Envelope`. I then edited the request in Fiddler and resent it, and now the server responded correctly. Here is the edited request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Body >
          <Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search"><queryXml>&lt;QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;SupportedFormats&gt;&lt;Format&gt;urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document&lt;/Format&gt;&lt;/SupportedFormats&gt;&lt;Context&gt;&lt;QueryText language='en-US' type='STRING'&gt;ACCORDION&lt;/QueryText&gt;&lt;/Context&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/QueryPacket&gt;
        </queryXml>
         </Query>
       </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

Isn't this weird? Am I missing something? Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Surround the text within the QueryPacket with CDATA and you should have correct behaviour without having to encode it first.

```
<![CDATA[your query]]>
```